# Android: Show two alert dialog side by side

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I need to display two alertdialog in the screen at the same time. If I just create two dialogs and show both of them, only one of them can have focus and another one will be in the background and the user will have to finish whatever needs to be done with the dialog with focus and then only they can access the dialog that's not on focus. So, if it was possible to have two dialogs to show at the same time with both of them having focus, that would solve my problem. I have actually changed the size and gravity of the dialog so that they are not on top of each other. One is in the left half of the screen and the other is in the right half. The only problem is that the dialog which was launched second has the focus and user has to finish input and close that dialog before they can access the first dialog that's in the background. So, My question is: Can I have two alertDialog show up at the same time side by side and not on top of each other and allow user to switch between two without closing any one?

My problem would also be solve if there was a way to get the layout from AlertDialog. If that's possible, I would create both the dialogs using alert dialog builder and then when it's time to show the dialogs instead of calling show(), I would just get the layouts from both and put them in my own custom linearlayout that has two linearlayouts in it.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be solved using two fragments where you create the layout yourself.